# Filter and copy rows based on condition

Tags: excel

Quick question, if I have a situation like this:

```
Sheet 1: 
A            B              C          D
92154   3.463259084 3.453471286 1.413287181
93035   176.4177028 175.9135241 71.26510962
92225   0.363370029 0.362457518 0.169233799
92203   451.6206281 450.3298896 182.8851898

Sheet 2: 
A            B              C          D
92203   451.6206281 450.3298896 182.8851898
92128   0.173532938 0.173036996 0.069032896
95991   1.118337369 1.11514121  0.435568007
93720   3.224674108 3.215457886 1.28377433
93430   2.047732493 2.042590079 0.974083112
```

And I want to copy all rows within Sheet 2, if the zip code (column A) does **not** match with Sheet 1. So in this case, I would ideally copy and paste the last 4 rows from Sheet 2 into another new tab sheet.

Comment: Are you looking for a an automated way to do this (i.e. programmatically) or you're OK with manual copying and pasting?

Comment: By VBA? If there's no way to do it formulaically then, I rather do it automated (there's >1000 rows so definitely don't want to do it manually)

Comment: Can you post a picture of your actual worksheet for us to help you please? Also, will there ever only be Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 on the first tab of your Excel Workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as adding an extra column with the formula `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A)),"Not in Sheet2", "In Sheet2")`, filling it down, filtering *out* the values you don't need (i.e. *Not in Sheet1*), and copying and pasting the rows you have left.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, won't this paste the rows that have zip codes that match with the zip codes on sheet 1? (I'm looking to copy and paste all rows that don't match) additionally, would this copy over the whole row? Or just one column?

Comment: if you filter OUT the undesired rows, default copy&paste behaviour in Excel will exclude hidden rows (different autofilter behaviour from when you hide columns manually)

Comment: I would, but there's >1000 rows in each sheets, so it'll be tough for me to look at the zip codes and filter out however many that don't match given I can't easily identify them

Comment: well, the whole idea in this answer is that you add a column and filter on this column to select only `#N/A` values. if you don't know how to add a column, check **Calculated Columns** in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: I misunderstood - going to give that a shot right now.